# "Not well-formed equation" using Mathematica's Solve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

First time using stackOverflow. :)

I'm trying to use mathematica to solve some simply polynomial equations (let's say in one variable) with constraints on the variable, e.g `|x| < 1`.

When I try something like:

```
Solve[x^2 == 4 && x^2 < 1, x]
```

I get an error stating that "x > 0 is not a well-formed equation".

The mathematica solve page even suggests this syntax on its second to last example, so I'm quite confused. (If it's relevant, I have version 7.) Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Solve was overhauled for version 8, where it now handles such inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mma v 8:

```
{Solve[x^2 == 4 && x^2 < 1, x],
 Solve[x^2 == 4 && (-1 < x < 1), x]} 

(* 
->{{},{}}
*)
```

Comment: Well, I'd say I put my comment before I saw your edit:). Deleting.

Answer (score 5):

`Solve` is not supposed to solve inequalities (M7). You can use `Reduce` to do that:

```
In[2]:= Reduce[x^2 == 4 && x^2 < 1, x]

Out[2]= False
```

Here is an example with `Solve`:

```
In[4]:= Solve[x^2 == 4 && x^4 == 16, x]

Out[4]= {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}
```